# Python sklearn: why must I set up a new estimator to plot a learning curve?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm using GridSearchCV to tune an SVM classifier, then plot a learning curve. However, unless I set up a fresh classifier before plotting the learning curve, I run into an IndexError and I'm not sure quite as to why.

My CV / classifier set up is below:

```
# Set up classifier
clf_untuned = OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(kernel='rbf', random_state=0, max_iter=1000))
cv = cross_validation.ShuffleSplit(data_image.shape[1], n_iter=10,
                                       test_size=0.1, random_state=0)

# Use cross validation / grid search to find optimal hyperparameters
if TRAINING_CROSS_VALIDATION == 1:
    params = {
        ...
    }
    clf_tuned = GridSearchCV(clf_untuned, cv=cv, param_grid=params)
    clf_tuned.fit(x_train, y_train)
    print('Best parameters: %s' % clf_tuned.best_params_)
else:
    clf_tuned = OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(kernel='rbf',
                                        C=100, gamma=0.00001, random_state=0, verbose=0))
    clf_tuned.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

I then go on to plot the learning curve, where plot_learning_curve duplicates the sklearn example (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_learning_curve.html). If I use the following code, then I get the following error at the 'learning_curve' line in plot_learning_curve:

```
# Plot learning curve for best params -- yields IndexError
plot_learning_curve(clf_tuned, title, x_train, y_train, ylim=(0.6, 1.05), cv=cv)
```

> IndexError: index 663 is out of bounds for size 70

However if instead I start a new classifer then everything works OK:

```
# Plot learning curve for best params -- functions correctly
estimator = OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(kernel='rbf',
                                        C=100, gamma=0.00001, random_state=0, verbose=0))
plot_learning_curve(estimator, title, x_train, y_train, ylim=(0.6, 1.05), cv=cv)
```

Why is this? Many thanks in advance, and other comments on my questionable implementation are welcome.

Comment: Could it be because you are fitting the classifier before using it as input in the first case? Try using clf_tuned.best_estimator_  to get the tuned classifier and give that directly as an input

Comment: Thank you @Prateek. I've changed plot_learning_curve(estimator, ...) to plot_learning_curve(clf_tuned.best_estimator_, ...), assuming this is what you meant?

Comment: Yeah. Does this work? I assume you are not fitting it before passing it as an argument

Comment: Firstly, thank you - this works but when I have fit it. If I dont fit it, then I get the error `AttributeError: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'best_estimator_'`. Why should I not fit it beforehand? Apologies for the delay, takes a while to run and I posted above accidentally early.

Comment: Hmm. I tried it with the sample datasets and GridSearchCV doesn't cause any problems really.

Comment: OK, I'll have to figure out why I'm getting that error myself. Are you able to explain why the classifier should not be fit to the training data before using it to plot the learning curve? Is this because to plot the learning curve sklearn is iteratively adding training examples, and to fit it to the training data would already have surpassed this?

Comment: Normally, you cannot fit a dataset to any classifier that has already been trained. But I got confused as the fit method of GridSearchCV essentially tells it to run the cross validation loop for tuning. So I assume if you passed it the best_estimator it worked?

Comment: Indeed it did, thank you.

Comment: No problem :). I just added the first comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was resolved by passing the best estimator obtained via grid search as clf_tuned.best_estimator_